# Strchr and strncpy Misuse

Tags: c

Hi im trying to find the - char and then place the leftmost characters into a string. Here i would like FUPOPER to be stored in program_id_DB, however when i run this code my output results to:

```
Character '-' found at position 8.
```

The prgmid contains FUPOPERL <-where is it getting this l?!?!

```
char data_DB[]="FUPOPER-$DSMSCM.OPER*.FUP";

char program_id_DB[10];

char program_name_DB_c[ZSYS_VAL_LEN_FILENAME];

char *pos = strchr(data_DB, '-');

if (pos)
     strncpy(program_id_DB,data_DB, pos-data_DB);


 printf("Character '-' found at position %d.\n",  pos-data_DB+1);

 printf("The prgmid contains %s\n",program_id_DB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `program_id_DB`, so it's free to contain anything it wants. Set it to zero before you start:

```
memset(program_id_DB, 0, 10);
```

(You need to `#include <string.h>` for `memset`.)

In fact, what you're doing is terribly dangerous because there's no guarantee that the string you pass to `printf` is null-terminated! Always zero the array before use and copy at most 9 non-null characters into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `\0` to mark the string's end.

A way to do it is: `memset(program_id_DB, 0, sizeof(program_id_DB));` before you `strncpy` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append a null-terminating character at the end of the `program_id_DB` string as `strncpy` does not do this automatically for you if you've already copied N characters (i.e., in your case you're copying a total of eight characters, so there will not be a null-terminating character copied into the buffer if you copy more than seven characters).  Either that, or zero-initialize your `program-id_DB` string using `memset` before using it with `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

[`strncpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html) is a bitch!

It doesn't terminate the string. You need to terminate the string yourself.

```
if (pos) {
    strncpy(program_id_DB,data_DB, pos-data_DB);
    program_id_DB[pos - data_DB] = 0;
}
```

And if the string is too small, strncpy will set the remainder with zeros.

```
strncpy(dst, src, 1000); /* always writes 1000 bytes, whether it needs to */
```